# Regex to find first comment in a JS file

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex (in JavaScript) that will match a multi line comment at the beginning of a JS file.

So far, I came up with this: `/^(\/\*[^\*\/]*\*\/)/g`

It works for a single line comment: https://regex101.com/r/ZS5PVI/1

But my problem is that it does not work for a multi line comment: https://regex101.com/r/ZS5PVI/2

Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: What if there are comment-like symbols in quotations?

Comment: @SamIam, that's why you need to use [a proper parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11141960/201952).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/201952), JavaScript ***cannot*** be parsed by regular expressions.  Attempting to do so *correctly* is futile.

Instead, you must use a parser that will correctly transform JavaScript source code into an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), which you may inspect programmatically.  Fortunately, there's libraries that [do the parsing for you](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS).

[Here's a working example that outputs the AST of this code:](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/UqsE7/)

```
/* this is a
multi-line
comment */

var test = "this is a string, /* and this is not a comment! */";

// ..but this is
```

Which gets us:

```
[
  "toplevel",
  [
    [
      {
        "name": "var",
        "start": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "value": "var",
          "line": 5,
          "col": 4,
          "pos": 57,
          "endpos": 60,
          "nlb": true,
          "comments_before": [
            {
              "type": "comment2",
              "value": " this is a\n    multi-line\n    comment ",
              "line": 1,
              "col": 4,
              "pos": 5,
              "endpos": 47,
              "nlb": true
            }
          ]
        },
        "end": {
          "type": "punc",
          "value": ";",
          "line": 5,
          "col": 67,
          "pos": 120,
          "endpos": 121,
          "nlb": false,
          "comments_before": []
        }
      },
      [
        [
          "test",
          [
            {
              "name": "string",
              "start": {
                "type": "string",
                "value": "this is a string, /* and this is not a comment! */",
                "line": 5,
                "col": 15,
                "pos": 68,
                "endpos": 120,
                "nlb": false,
                "comments_before": []
              },
              "end": {
                "type": "string",
                "value": "this is a string, /* and this is not a comment! */",
                "line": 5,
                "col": 15,
                "pos": 68,
                "endpos": 120,
                "nlb": false,
                "comments_before": []
              }
            },
            "this is a string, /* and this is not a comment! */"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Now it's just a matter of looping over the AST and extracting what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Your suggested Regex desn't work because there is a `*` in the comment. Additionally, it will only look for comments that are right at the beginning of the file.

Try using this instead:

```
/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//
```

Comment: That matches everything between the first `/*` to the last `*/`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty good discussion of this problem [at this link](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html). Does that help you?

His solution was:

`/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/
```

[This page](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html) goes into some detail on how to find multi-line comments.

Comment: LOL I have to +1 this since we posted the same link. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that will match any multi-line or single-line comments:

```
/(\/\*.*?\*\/|\/\/[^\n]+)/
```

If you just want multi-line matches, ditch the second half:

```
/\/\*.*?\*\//
```

For both of these, make sure you have `s` flag set so the `.` matches new lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no javascript expert but it seems C/C++ comments have to be taken into account.
Properly done means quotes have to be accounted for in the process (escapes and all that).

Below are two regex methods that work. Regex 1 finds the first C-style comment directly, as soon as it matches, it is found. Regex 2 is a general case. It finds either C style, C++ style, or non-comments, is global, and allows you to break when you find what you want.

Tested here http://ideone.com/i1UWr

Code

```
var js = '\
// /* C++ comment  */      \\\n\
   /* C++ comment (cont) */  \n\
/* t "h /* is"               \n\
 is first C-style /*         \n\
//  comment */               \n\
and /*second C-style*/       \n\
then /*last C-style*/        \n\
';

var cmtrx1 = /^(?:\/\/(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n|(?:"(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[^\/"'\\]*))+(\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/)/;

var cmtrx2 = /(\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/)|(\/\/(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?)\n|(?:"(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[\S\s][^\/"'\\]*)/g;

//
print ('Script\n===========\n'+js+'\n===========\n\n');

var match;
//
print ("Using Regex 1\n---------------\n");
if ((match=cmtrx1.exec( js )) != null)
    print ("Found C style comment:\n'" + match[1] + "'\n\n");
//
print ("Using Regex 2\n---------------\n");
while ((match=cmtrx2.exec( js )) != null)
{
   if (match[1] != undefined)
   {
        print ("- C style :\n'" + match[1] + "'\n");
        // break;     // uncomment to stop after first c-style match
   }
   // comment this to not print it
   if (match[2] != undefined)
   {
        print ("- C++ style :\n'" + match[2] + "'\n");
   }
}
```

Output

```
Script
===========
// /* C++ comment  */      \
   /* C++ comment (cont) */  
/* t "h /* is"               
 is first C-style /*         
//  comment */               
and /*second C-style*/       
then /*last C-style*/        

===========


Using Regex 1
---------------

Found C style comment:
'/* t "h /* is"               
 is first C-style /*         
//  comment */'


Using Regex 2
---------------

- C++ style :
'// /* C++ comment  */      \
   /* C++ comment (cont) */  '

- C style :
'/* t "h /* is"               
 is first C-style /*         
//  comment */'

- C style :
'/*second C-style*/'

- C style :
'/*last C-style*/'
```

Expanded Regex's

```
Regex 1:

/^(?:\/\/(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n|(?:"(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[^\/"'\\]*))+(\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/)/

     /^
     (?:
          \/\/
          (?: [^\\] | \\\n? )*?
          \n
       |
          (?:
               "
               (?: \\[\S\s] | [^"\\] )*
               "
            |  '
               (?: \\[\S\s] | [^'\\] )*
               '
            |  [^\/"'\\]*
          )
     )+
1    (
          \/\* [^*]* \*+
          (?: [^\/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
          \/
1    )
     /


Regex 2:

/(\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/)|(\/\/(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?)\n|(?:"(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[\S\s][^\/"'\\]*)/g

     /
1    (
          \/\* [^*]* \*+
          (?: [^\/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
          \/
1    )
  |
2    (
          \/\/
          (?: [^\\] | \\\n? )*?
2    )
     \n
  |
     (?:
          "
          (?: \\[\S\s] | [^"\\] )*
          "
       |  '
          (?: \\[\S\s] | [^'\\] )*
          '
       |  [\S\s][^\/"'\\]*
     )
     /g
```